# Git merge conflict (hypothetical scenario)

Tags: git, github

Hi I'm rather new to using git, but I was wondering how the following hypothetical example would be solved:

There are two individuals (A and B) contributing to a remote repo on one branch (master). We're going to assume B is up to date with the repo, but A is not. A has just modified a new line of code, and has just tried pushing to the repo, and has been informed that he needs to pull to be up to date. Upon pulling he is met with a merge conflict, and is able to solve it. After doing so, A pushes to the repo successfully. Now B realizes that A's update is important, and decides that he needs to pull from the repo, but he already has changes locally, so he just stashes for the time being. After pulling and then applying the stash, B realizes that he is met with the same merge conflict A was met with earlier. Now my question is in these scenario would the people pulling from a repo always have to solve a merge conflict again even though another individual has done so before, or is there another way around this?

Much thanks for any assistance.

Comment: The scenario does not seem to be able to happen. How come B has the same merge conflict with A when B has already started with an up-to-date codebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case never quite occurs.  The reason is that one of the inputs to the merge operation has automatically changed.  However, person B—who I'll call Bob below—*can* see merge conflicts.

Remember that *merging*, in Git, is an action involving commits.  That is, when we are doing a merge—the verb form, *to merge*—we find some commits and do our work.  Note, too, that each commit represents a *complete snapshot:* all the files, frozen in time as of that particular commit.  If you want to see what your files looked like yesterday, or last year, or whatever, they are there, in the commit(s) made on that day.

There are *three* inputs to a merge operation!  We, as the human running Git, specify *one* of them directly:

```
$ git merge origin/develop
```

for instance.  The name `origin/develop` resolves to some particular commit ID—a big ugly hash ID string like `5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7`, which is a commit that we have in our repository, that we got earlier, probably by running `git fetch`.  (Remember that `git pull` is essentially a convenience command meaning: *run `git fetch` for me, then as soon as that finishes, run a second Git command, typically `git merge`, for me*.)

The second input to the merge is *whatever the current commit is*.  That is, before we ran `git merge` (perhaps via `git pull`), we ran a `git checkout` command:

```
$ git checkout develop
```

This selects the *latest commit on the branch*, because the definition of a branch name *is* "the latest commit on the branch".  This means that branch names keep changing *which commit they mean*, over time.  To see which commit `master` is right now, or which commit `develop` is right now, you can run `git rev-parse master` or `git rev-parse develop`—that will spit out he current hash ID.  Run this again later, when there are more commits, and you'll get a different hash ID.

#### Drawing the history

So, with that in mind, it's always worth drawing the *commit graph*.  The commit graph *is* the history in a repository, because history in Git is nothing but commits.

If you have not drawn commit graphs before, this takes some practice.  There are a lot of ways to draw them—or view them, in a browser or GUI, though I have a healthy distrust of GUIs because a lot of them lie (usually for good reasons having to do with performing well, but still, it's annoying).  There are a lot of ways to do this, but I like to do it horizontally for StackOverflow postings:

```
          o--o--o   <-- develop (HEAD)
         /
...--o--*
         \
          o--o   <-- origin/develop
```

In these drawings, the most recent commits are at the right, with time moving backwards towards the left.  The *branch names* point to the rightmost (newest) commits, because by definition a name *is* the *last* commit in its branch.  We—and Git—must start at the end, and move backwards to earlier commits, to see how things progressed.

From this drawing, we can see that our `develop` has three commits—the round `o` nodes—on it that aren't on the shared history, while our `origin/develop` has two commits on it that aren't on the shared history.

The shared history starts at commit `*` and continues backwards in time.  Commit `*`, in this drawing, is the *merge base* of commits `develop` and `origin/develop`.  **When Git is doing a true merge**—doing the *to merge* part of the process of merging—**the three inputs are the merge base, the `HEAD` commit (`--ours`), and the other commit (`--theirs`).**

The way Git does the merge is now actually pretty simple to see.  Because each commit is a full snapshot, Git starts by extracting the merge base snapshot to a temporary area.  Then it extracts *our* commit—well, it's already there, really—and *their* commit, and now it runs *two separate comparisons*, which we can reproduce one at a time ourselves using `git diff`.  We first find the hash ID of commit `*` (by looking at the graph, perhaps), then run:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> HEAD             # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-*> origin/develop   # what they changed
```

All `git merge` has to do now is *combine these changes*.  Start with the base files.  Then, wherever we changed a file, if they didn't change that file, use ours.  Wherever they changed a file and we didn't, use theirs.  Wherever we *both* changed *the same* file, combine the changes.

Merge conflicts occur if / when the combination of the two change-sets tries to change the *same* lines of the *same* files.  In that case, Git leaves all three original copies of the file around (hidden away in Git's *index*), and puts its best effort at combining the changes, plus some conflict markers, into the work-tree.

If Git encounters no conflicts at all, Git makes a new commit.  Or, after you've manually fixed up the mess Git left behind if there were conflicts, *you* make the final commit of the result.  This commit looks a little odd in our graph, because it has *two* previous commits, rather than the usual one.  I'll give this new commit a letter-ID (not a true hash ID, just a stand-in), `M`:

```
          o--o--o--M   <-- develop (HEAD)
         /        /
...--o--*        /
         \      /
          o----o   <-- origin/develop
```

This kind of commit is *a merge*, or *merge as a noun:* a two-parent commit, with the two parents being the old `HEAD` (parent #1) and the other commit (#2).

#### Now suppose your persons A (Alice) and B (Bob) continue working

You propose that Alice did the merge and then ran `git push`.  When Alice does this, assuming her `git push` succeeds, that gets yet another Git repository to call commit `M` the tip of *its* `develop`.  Perhaps this third repository is on GitHub, for instance:

```
          o--o--o
         /       \
...--o--o         M   <-- develop (HEAD)
         \       /
          o-----L
```

I've drawn this a little differently, but it's the same set of commits.  There's no `origin/develop` here, just the merge commit `M` leading back to both previous commits.  I've also un-marked the old share-point, and given a letter `L` for Bob's *current* commit as of right now, because we're going to need to talk about it soon.

Now Bob runs `git fetch` in *his* repository, to pick up Alice's work.  While Bob has no new commits of his own yet, he acquires the new ones.  Note that his `develop` already exists and currently points to commit `L`:

```
          o--o--o
         /       \
...--o--o         M   <-- origin/develop
         \       /
          o-----L   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Note that Bob's `develop` is the end of his branch!  If he has uncommitted changes, he can run `git stash` to save them in a commit—actually two commits, but let's pretend just one for now—that's on *no* branch:

```
          o--o--o
         /       \
...--o--o         M   <-- origin/develop
         \       /
          o-----L   <-- develop (HEAD)
                 \
                  S   [stash]
```

Now Bob can run `git merge --ff-only` (or `git pull`, which will do another fetch that does nothing since there's nothing newer than `M`, then do a fast-forward not-really-a-merge "merge") to make *Bob*'s `develop` point to commit `M`:

```
          o--o--o
         /       \
...--o--o         M   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
         \       /
          o-----L
                 \
                  S   [stash]
```

Bob can now apply and drop (or "pop") the stash to get the changes into his work-tree.  If this works, they will be ready to add and commit.  Then Bob makes a new commit, which we can draw as `N`:

```
          o--o--o
         /       \
...--o--o         M--N   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
         \       /
          o-----L
```

The contents of `N` already include the contents of `M`, because `git stash apply` took `S`, compared it to its parent, and then made the same *changes* to whatever was in `M`.

#### When Bob can see a conflict

The point at which Bob can see a conflict is not during the fetching and fast-forwarding, but rather at the time Bob runs `git stash apply` (or `git stash pop` which starts by running `git stash apply`).  This, in fact, runs another merge!  But it runs a merge that *won't* end with a *merge commit*.  This only does the *to merge* verb part of the action.

This merge has commit `S` as its last, "other commit" input.  The middle input is `HEAD`—commit `M`—as the current commit as usual, and the first input is the merge base of the two, which is commit `L`:

```
          o--o--o
         /       \
...--o--o         M   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
         \       /
          o-----L
                 \
                  S   [stash]
```

Git compares (diffs) `L` and `M` to find out what "we" did.  (Of course, it's actually what *Alice* did, more or less, but Git doesn't care.)  It compares `L` to `S` to see what "they" (really, Bob) did.  Then it combines, or tries to combine, the two change-sets, exactly as for a regular merge.

If all goes well, `git stash` stops there.  There is no new commit yet.  If it goes badly, `git stash` stops with a merge conflict, leaving Bob to resolve the merge conflict.  When Bob is done, the next commit Bob makes will be an ordinary commit, not a merge commit.

If Bob uses `git stash pop` and there is a merge conflict, Git stops after the `apply` step, and Bob still has the stash: he must run `git stash drop` to discard it after he fixes up the mess.  But if Git thinks the merge went well, and Bob ran `git stash pop`, *Git* will run `git stash drop` for Bob.  So one must be a little careful with `git stash`: sometimes it does both apply-and-drop, but sometimes it fails after the apply and doesn't do the drop part.

(I mainly recommend avoiding `git stash`, but if you are going to use it, do the apply and drop separately, to avoid accidentally dropping the stash if it applies in a way *Git* thinks is clean, but was actually a mistake on your part.  This really does happen, even to Git experts, and recovering from that is a pain.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was a great read, and I think I'm a lot more comfortable with the merge conflicts concept in git.